# how to extract ip and userid from unformed string

Tags: python

I have a string

```
 Jun 11 02:47:04 webwork-tlv tcp: 2013-06-11 02:47:04 - ive - [84.11.11.11] hacker(Secure ID)[Manage System] - Host Checker policy 'Machine center' passed on host 84.11.11.11  for user 'hacker'
```

some string looks like that

```
 Jun 11 00:13:26 webwork-tlv tcp: 2013-06-11 00:13:25 - ive - [10.11.12.19] hacker(Secure ID)[Manage System] - Sensor tlv-entid-001 - timestamp=[Tue Jun 11 02:23:42 2013 ] severity=[4] policyStr=[IDP 20110132] category=[attack] protocol=[tcp] attackStr=[HTTP:XSS:HTML-SCRIPT-IN-URL-VA] rulebaseStr=[IDS] rulebaseType=[Main Rule Base] srcAddr=[10.11.12.19] srcPort=[3333] dstAddr=[66.11.12.13] dstPort=[80] action=[drop] policyVersion=[41] ruleNumber=[3]
```

I want to extract date in the beginning, ip between [] however if it is internal ip(starting with 10 or 192) no need to extract and id hacker before(SecureID)

so result should be ip:84.11.11.11, id:hacker

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are all of the expected strings in this format?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(\[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\]) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)")
>>> r = regex.search(string)

# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'[84.11.11.11]', u'hacker')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of tedious, but:

```
s = "Jun 11 02:47:04 webwork-tlv tcp: 2013-06-11 02:47:04 - ive - [84.11.11.11] hacker(Secure ID)[Manage System] - Host Checker policy 'Machine center' passed on host 84.11.11.11  for user 'hacker'."
parts = s.split('[')[1].split(']')
{'ip': parts[0], 'id': parts[1].split('(Secure ID)')[0]}
```